# Grok filter with vertical lines in logs

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch, grok

I'm trying to use grok filters with a log with vertical lines "|".

Example:

`D:\Files\test.txt||Filtertest||2015/07/24 02:10:25 PM||Myname`

I'm trying the greedydata filter, but don't know how to stop for the "|" character.

```
${GREEDYDATA:filename}||%{WORD:filter}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Patterns are really regexps, and the pipe character means "OR" in a regexp.  To remove that meaning, escape it:

```
foo\|\|bar
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  So the filter should be this?  %{GREEDYDATA:filename}\|\|%{WORD:filter}

Comment: Yes, you have to escape ("\") the pipe ("|").

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution for this.  I used the gsub command to replace all the | characters with commas, which I can easily filter using grok.

```
gsub => ["message", "[|]", ","]
```